# Addition interpreted as string AngularJS

Tags: angularjs, addition

I’m having trouble adding two numbers in the following code:

.js:

```
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);
app.controller('myCtrl', function($scope) {
$scope.size = {

total_size_1 : {s_size : "1st size", a : "10", b : "7"}, 
total_size_2 : {s_size : "2nd size", a : "12", b : "4"},
total_size_3 : {s_size : "3rd size", a : "11", b : "1"}
}
});
```

markup:

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.8/angular.min.js"> </script>
<script src="sum_test.js"></script>

<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="myCtrl">
<p> Select size: <select ng-model="selectedSize" ng-options="y.s_size for (x, y) in size"></select>
</p>

<span>Selected size: {{selectedSize.s_size}}</span><br />
<span>Factor: {{selectedSize.a + selectedSize.b}}</span>
```

The problem is the {{selectedSize.a + selectedSize.b}}. Instead of adding a + b from the scope, it just adds the two numbers together as if it were a string ’ab’. In the "1st size", that would be 10+7, which would yield 17, but instead it shows 107.
How can I resolve this?

Comment: *as if it were a string*: well, they **are** strings, not numbers. If you want numbers, use numbers, not strings: `a : 10, b : 7`

Answer (score 1):

Your issue is within your object. The data type of the "numbers" you are trying to add together are actually strings.

```
a = "10" //represented as a string.
b = a + a //b would equal "1010"
c = 10 //represented as an int/numerical data type
d = c + c //d would equal 20
```

Simply remove the quotes and your code should work. Like so:

```
total_size_1 : {s_size : "1st size", a : 10, b : 7}
```

Answer (score -1):

Parse as numbers.

E.g. as integers:

```
<span>Factor: {{parseInt(selectedSize.a) + parseInt(selectedSize.b)}}</span>
```